# What pickaxes can mine gold?

Tags: terraria

I have been trying to figure out this question since 2016, and I still haven’t found the answer yet, what pickaxes can mine gold.
I looked up this question on google and it just said what the item is, not the pickaxes.

Answer (score 7):

In my worlds, any pick can do it. Try a copper one to start with. Remember though, [stronger pickaxes can mine faster](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pickaxe_power).

Answer (score -9):

An iron, copper, lead, and all sort of pickaxe that is made using materials that are better than wood can mine gold.

Comment: There is no wooden pickaxe, copper is the lowest.